# Partial GPL 2 legacy code into a GPL 3 project

Tags: gpl, legacy

I plan to import works from a Java GPL2 project into a GPL3 one.

1. How must I "head" all my project derivating sources files : must I put the GPL2 license of the original project (saying that "This file is part of PROJECT_NAME ...") above my project one ?
2. How should be the LICENSING file of the whole projet : must I put both licenses in it ?
3. I don't know yet if I will import nearly complete classes or just some pieces of codes from the original project. Anyway, how should I inform the user (saying, in a about dialog) : is saying "Work derivated from PROJECT_NAME project" enough ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How do I upgrade from (L)GPLv2 to (L)GPLv3?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#v3HowToUpgrade)

> First, include the new version of the license in your package. If
>   you're using LGPLv3 in your project, be sure to include copies of both
>   GPLv3 and LGPLv3, since LGPLv3 is now written as a set of additional
>   permissions on top of GPLv3.
>
> Second, replace all your existing v2 license notices (usually at the
>   top of each file) with the new recommended text available on the GNU
>   licenses howto. It's more future-proof because it no longer includes
>   the FSF's postal mailing address.
>
> Of course, any descriptive text (such as in a README) which talks
>   about the package's license should also be updated appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I refer to the imported work of the old project : is saying "Derivated from PROJECTNAME project" -and putting the GPL3 header- enough ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the old project yours?  If it is, just upgrade the license.  If it isn't, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#v2v3Compatibility

Comment: No,the original project is not mine. It is Jose : http://jose-chess.sourceforge.net/ . And it seems that it is not in GPL v2+, but just GPL v2.So I think I must release it under GPL v2. Anyway, how should I point that this will be my work, derivated from the Jose project ?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167935/proper-attribution-of-derived-work-in-a-gpl-project?rq=1